# Send http request to api.ticktick.com returns error 500

Tags: javascript, python, dart

Postman works well.

Code on js also works:

```
const axios = require('axios');
axios({
  method: 'post',
  url: 'https://api.ticktick.com/open/v1/task',
  headers: {Authorization: "[access token]"},
  data: {title: 'mytitle'}
});
```

Code on Python returns error 500:

```
import requests    
headers = {'Authorization': '[access token]'}    
response = requests.post('https://api.ticktick.com/open/v1/task',
                         data={'title': 'mytitle'},
                         headers=headers)
```

Code on Dart also returns error 500:

```
var url = Uri.https('api.ticktick.com', 'open/v1/task');
    var response = await http.post(url,headers: {"Authorization": "[access token]"}, body: {'title': 'mytitle'});
```

Comment: You should probably ask them, because `500` usually means that unexpected error occurred on their side

Comment: I'll try but I'm sure the problem with the code, I think with url.

Answer (score 0):

In Python you must use `json` argument when sending data.

```py
import requests


requests.post(
    url='https://api.ticktick.com/open/v1/task',
    headers={
        'Authorization': 'Bearer {your_token}',
    },
    json={
        'title': 'mytitle',
    }
)
```

Answer (score -1):

Don't use the v1, instead use the v2; even though there is no documentation. For information you can see the source of https://github.com/glasslion/ticktick-python/tree/master/ticktick

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: That source uses userapi, not openapi, which the questioner works with.